# Which datastructure to use? Indexed data structure inserted out of order

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to figure out which datastructure to use for my situation. What I'm looking for is very (very) similar to `ArrayList`, except that a Java `ArrayList` throws a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` "if the index > size()".

I will know the index of each item as it gets inserted, but I will not know the total capacity (precluding a general array) nor will I receive the items in the sorted order.

Basically, what could I use to hold this:

```
|   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |   6   |  ...  |
| Item3 |  ---  | Item1 | Item6 |  ---  | Item3 |       |
```

(new insert)

```
|   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |   6   |   7   |   8   |
| Item3 |  ---  | Item1 | Item6 |  ---  | Item3 |  ---  | Item7 | <--- This would throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in Java
```

(new insert)

```
|   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |   6   |   7   |   8   |
| Item3 |  ---  | Item1 | Item6 | Item2 | Item3 |  ---  | Item7 |
```

etc...

EDIT: The suggestion to insert nulls was a good one. I'll likely go that route. But just for the record, `ArrayList::ensureCapacity` is not sufficient to increase the "size" of the `ArrayList`, only the capacity. Take this code:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.ensureCapacity(10);
list.add(5, "Five");
```

throws this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:643)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:455)
    at test4.Test18.main(Test18.java:20)
```

When the "size" is 0, the only acceptable index is '0'. When the size is 1, you can insert at 0 or 1. I'm sure there's a good reason for implementing `ArrayList` this way, but I can't see one.

Comment: Simply check the size before getting it using index to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. For sorting can you try with `Set`?

Comment: So if I'm inserting an element that is > size(), what do I do with it? Note: `ArrayList` "capacity" != `ArrayList::size()`.

Comment: "When the "size" is 0, the only acceptable index is '0'. When the size is 1, you can insert at 0 or 1" Actually, you have a classic off-by-one error here ;)

Comment: @NiklasB., I don't think so. ;) The index must be <= the size. So if the size is 1, you can insert at 0 (before the current element) or 1 (after the current element).

Comment: @ryvantage Try it. Your assumption is wrong, the index must be < size because Java uses 0-based indexing.

Comment: @NiklasB., This code: `        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.ensureCapacity(10);
        list.add(0, "Zero");
        System.out.println(list);` does not throw an error. Even though 0 is not less than 0.

Comment: @ryvantage After the `add`, we have `list.size() == 1` though. I guess it depends on what indices you are talking about. I think for your scenario (which I assumed) you don't want to use `add`, you want to use `set`. I think the result of `list.add(null); list.add(null); list.add(1, "One"); list.add(0, "Zero")` might surprise you (although I might be mistaken). If it does surprise you indeed, [consult the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E))

Comment: Oh, ok. I see the disconnect. Yes, you're right. `set` would be more appropriate. I guess you would `add` the nulls and `set` the values. And, yes, of course, the index must be < size if you use `set`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just resize the array appropriately before accessing the index:

```
while (list.size() < index + 1)
    list.add(null);
list.set(index, value);
```

If you are writing far "into the future", you could *additionally* use `list.ensureCapacity(index + 1)` before the loop, but that's at best a constant-factor optimization. The runtime is *O(N)* anyway, where *N* is the highest index you access during the execution of your algorithm.

Of course that approach will waste space if your data set is sparse and most of the slots are still empty after all operations have been finished. In that case consider using a hash table instead of an array (`HashMap<Integer, T>` in Java).

Comment: `ensureCapacity` won't increase the size. Read my edit. But `list.add(null)` is a good suggestion. I'll do that.

Comment: @ryvantage I didn't say it would. I suggested it as an optimization. Say the first index you access is 1000. Then the array would probably be relocated log_2(1000) ~ 10 times if you append repeatedly. If you use `ensureCapacity`, it's going to be realocated exactly once.

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Map<Integer, Item>`.

A `HashMap` is very good for use as a sparse array. If you need to maintain iteration order then a `TreeMap` would work, but it's more computationally expensive.

For a `HashMap`, `put` and `get` is guaranteed `O(1)`.

For a `TreeMap`, `put` and `get` is guaranteed `O(lg n)`.

A `Map` will never throw an exception if the element is not present - you will just get back `null`.

You do not need to increase the size of the `Map` to `1000` if you only have an element at `0` and one at `999`. The size will only be `2`.

Comment: I guess my hesitation with `Map` was the retrieval of the items, but the array will only be sparse during insertion... After insertion, it will be a full array (no sparse values).

Comment: @ryvantage Depending on how many reads there are after a write, if you really need speed, you can copy the `Map` to an `Item[]` once all the items are inserted. Obviously the read won't be as fast from a `Map` as from an array, but if you have a good `hashCode` then a `HashMap` is actually very similar to an array access.

Comment: @BoristheSpider If every element gets inserted eventually (or rather, if the data set is dense enough), using a dynamic array like `ArrayList` is better than using a `Map` by a factor of Theta(log n) (and better than `HashMap` by a non-negligible constant factor)

Comment: @BoristheSpider, copying the Map's `values()` array won't guarantee order. The `Map` will need to be iterated over and manually copied to grab the elements in order. Even a `LinkedHashMap` is insufficient.. it only guarantees insertion order.

Comment: @ryvantage Actually [`TreeMap#values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#values()) *does* return the values in ascending order of their keys

Comment: @NiklasB. I reckon you're right - if the whole thing is going to be full in the end; you don't gain much by using a `Map`.